# Installation not giving option to install along side Windows 8?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, ubiquity

I'm trying to install (from DVD) Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my desktop computer along side Windows 8.1.

I am never given the option to do so.

I never get this screen:

[image: Install - Installation type - This computer currently has Windows 7 on it. What would you like to do?]

Comment: Windows 8 is probably installed in UEFI mode, is your DVD booting via UEFI or via legacy?

Comment: I guess I'm dumb.... but I don't have a clue.  :)

Comment: why don't you try installing in different partition it will be fast and more stable

Comment: I finally got Ubuntu installed along side Win 8.1. Just had to create a new partition. Now I have a NEW issue. I have 2 monitors set up but Ubuntu will not allow the mouse to travel between them as does Win 8. Am I missing something here?  Help!  :)

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/a/521195/40581

Answer (score 3):

After installing Windows 7 or 8, you need to have a `logical partition` to install Ubuntu alongside it. If you don't have a logical partition then the option `Install Ubuntu alongside Windows` is missing.

To get it back, do the following.

1. Install [EASEUS Partition Master Professional Edition](http://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/epm-pro.html) (NB: Quite Expensive) or [free trial download here](http://easeus-partition-master-professional.en.softonic.com)
2. Run EASEUS Partition Master then click `Go to main screen` option.
3. Here, select the partition which you want to install Ubuntu in, and right-click on it and select `Delete Partition`. Now it's unallocated (Free space).
4. If you don't have this partition you can shrink another one other partition. Just right-click on other partition and select `Resize/Move Partition` (20GB is enough). Don't format the free space.
5. Now right-click on `* unallocated` and select `Create Partition`. Under the `Create as` drop down, select `Logical` and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
6. Click the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button at the top of EASEUS window (under view menu) then click <kbd>Yes</kbd>. This operation needs to restart your computer to completing
7. Finish

If you insert the Ubuntu installation media (USB/DVD) you will see `Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7/8`.

Comment: Why not use `diskmgmt.msc` in Windows?

Comment: @LiveWireBT Ok that is also another option. you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8.1. I disabled secure boot in the bios, installed Ubuntu to its own partition then booted using the boot repair CD. selected automatic repair and grub was installed correctly and both windows and Ubuntu where successfuly added to the boot menu.

Here is the link I followed, it worked perfectly for me.

http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I think the link provided was complete and concise, I think the whole guide is an essential part. Did I really have to be marked down 2 point ?

Comment: I am sure the link is good, but the point is " it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference", i.e. include the parts of the link in the answer, and then keep the link for reference.

Comment: OK, well I will bare that in mind, thanks for the advice. Still not certain the information on that link can be broken down into essential parts though :)

Comment: It can, just the headings and a short paragrah for each.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Fast Startup worked for me. Use the instructions provided to do that from this link  https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/windows

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a problem like that.

1. Turn off Fast boot on Win8.
2. Disable UEFI in Bios.
3. Load Ubuntu From Ubuntu Website.

I've tested on Acer Aspire IZ.