# installation Ubuntu 14.01 on a different partition with Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mbr

Please assist me. I am eager to install Ubuntu 14.01 on a different partition but I do not know how to do it. I have HP with Windows 7 pre-installed then I upgraded to Windows 8.1

Please show me how to make a dedicated partition to install Ubuntu 14.01.

Please find the partition that I have:

```
partition:  /dev/sda1  NTFS      label system     922.50  KB
            /dev/sda2  NTFS                       199.00 MIB    flags: boot
            /dev/sda3  NTFS      label receovery  488.77  GB 
            /dev/sda4  unknown                     16     GB 
            unallocated                             1    MIB
```

Comment: Try with my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488119/installation-not-giving-option-to-install-along-side-windows-8/488141#488141)

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, when you start the Ubuntu installation, it will detect Windows partitions and guide you through making space for Ubuntu. If it doesn't, you have to manually partition, which isn't hard at all for someone like me, but I use Gentoo, so that's different. Anyways, if the Ubuntu installer cannot detect windows paritions, you will have to click on the options that is under "Install Ubuntu" which is called "Something Else", after you click that, you will have to make the Windows Partition smaller to make room for Ubuntu, I suggest >40GB. Then you will make a new parition, which you will have to set as ext4 or btrfs, and choose the / mount point. If you are low on RAM, leave an extra 4 - 8 GB to partition as swap.

Comment: Use Windows to shrink the Windows partition & reboot to make it run chkdsk. If Windows 8 make sure fast boot is off. But since a BIOS install with all 4 partitions you have to backup and delete one partition. Usually the vendor tools is the best to backup. http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-laptop-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu  Once you delete one primary partition, you can create the extended partition and have as many logical partitions as you want.

Comment: yes I did that but now, my windows is not loading, only ubuntu, what to do?

Comment: you mean on the grub menu windows isnt present?