# Why isn't there an option for installing alongside an os anymore?

Tags: system-installation

i recently got a computer with windows 8.1 and i hate it. so i decided to get ubuntu 14.04.1 lts seeing as i loved 12.04 so much on my last pc. i booted from disk and everything was fine, until i got to the installation type screen, it only gave me the replace current os, and the something else option. the usual option to install alongside the current os wasn't available.

i searched online and found nothing regarding this issue, not even a mention of it. does anyone know why this happened? or how to rectify this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/488119/installation-not-giving-option-to-install-along-side-windows-8

Answer (score 1):

Options appear when that option has a situation that validates that option to show.

Odd sentence I know. So with some examples ...

- Replace Ubuntu only appears when you have another Ubuntu installed.
- Replace windows only appears when you have a windows system installed.

And in your case ...

The OS you currently have installed probably takes up ALL of your partitions. For "install alongside" to appear there needs to be a partition to install your 2nd operating next to. In other words: you need "unallocated space" or an empty partition.